# Is there anyway to rearrange my uploads so that it'll show up first instead of last when I do upload it?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using MySQL and I think it has something to do with Id's. I want every new image I upload to show up first in a order. Here is my code:

This allows the images to display:

```
<?php
        $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "photos");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM images";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<a href='uploads/".$row['image']."'> ";
                echo "<img  id='img_div' src='uploads/".$row['image']."'/>";
                echo "</a>";

        }
?>
```

Here is my image structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `images` (`id`, `image`, `text`) VALUES .....

ALTER TABLE `images`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `images`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=129;
```

Comment: assuming the `images` table has an auto-increment ID field then use the `order by id desc` at the end of the sql. Incidentally - you cannot have duplicate IDs so repeatedly setting `id="img_div"` is incorrect

Comment: Ok I did the order by id desc it no help, unless I reupload everything. Also, the img_div is used so that every image has a size that I desire.

Comment: The HTML id attribute problem @RamRaider mentioned can be fixed with `id='img_div'.$row['id']`, again assuming the `images` table has an auto-increment ID field named `id`.

Comment: @SarahJ.Smith that is invalid html. Ids must be distinct. You should not target your css selector at a specific `#id`.

Comment: You want to use a class name to get the images all the same size.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add the `images` table structure to your question.  Also, you should have [no PHP close tag](http://mitsloan.mit.edu/shared/content/PHP_Code_Style_Guide.php#no-php-closing-tag-at-eof) at the end of your file.

Comment: Ok when I use `id='img_div'.$row['id']` I get string error messages. Also I will change the id to class.

Comment: you don't need to use a unique id - set a class and use that class in your css to set the image size. You say that using `order by id desc` didn't help - what was the result? Each file is presumably recorded in the db when it is uploaded so they should be sequential?

Comment: Exactly. Nothing changed. Also I updated my question.

Comment: Just FYI, your question is about php w/MySQL.  It has nothing to do with phpMyAdmin.  phpMyAdmin is a php app that lets you interact through your browser with mysql.  You are either using MySQL or MariaDB (a FOSS fork of MySQL by the MySQL originator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Should do the trick!

Comment: Yes!! Thank you!! @HoogleyBoogley :

Comment: @SarahJ.Smith Great! Have fun with your project!

Comment: I suggested exactly this in the first comment but was told it had already been tried by the @op and didn't work

Comment: Sorry! I just didn't understand it fully. @RamRaider